# Strange RegExp behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I need to capture every `%{string}` sequience in a string.
I am created a RegExp: 
`/[^%]*(%{[^}]+})?/g`, 
which works correctly on string `Lorem %{ipsum} dolor %{sit} amet adipiscing aenean %{consectetuer}` on regex101.com (https://regex101.com/r/aB2xL5/1), but incorrect in JS: 

`var a='Lorem %{ipsum} dolor %{sit} amet adipiscing aenean %{consectetuer}'.match(/[^%]*(%{[^}]+})?/g);

console.log(a); //['Lorem %{ipsum}', ' dolor %{sit}', ' amet adipiscing aenean %{consectetuer}', '']`

What i am doing wrong?

What i need:

   `Input string: 'abc %{def} ghi %{jkl}'
   Output array: ['%{def}','%{jkl}']`

Comment: you need to access the first capturing group

Comment: I need to get array (['%{def}','%{jkl}']) from string "abc %{def} ghi %{jkl}"

Comment: `input.match( /%\{[^}]+\}/g );`

Comment: Thank you, Thomas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, don't access the whole match which, even on regex101, contains more than you need, but rather access the first group of the match.

To do so, use `Regex.prototype.exec` instead of `String.prototype.match`:

```
var regex=/[^%]*(%{[^}]+})?/g;
var data='Lorem %{ipsum} dolor %{sit} amet adipiscing aenean %{consectetuer}';
var result=[];
var match;
while (match = regex.exec(data)) {
  result.push(match[1]);  // match the first group of the result
}
```

Edit : I just saw Thomas' comment, which is much better than this solution. I'll leave it here because it does indeed solve your problem and explains how to capture groups, but you should use his regex.